# Demonstrate that s(w)=-u

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\vec u$ and $\vec w$ be to linearly independent vectors on $\Bbb R^2$. Let $s$ be the simmetry on the axis $\vec u-\vec w$. Demonstrate that $s(\vec w)=-\vec u$.

I can't figure this out because -$\vec u$ is not orthogonal to $\vec u-\vec w$.

Comment: Are you also given that they have the same magnitude, by any chance? (since reflection should preserve magnitude, I don't think this makes any sense if we can have $\lvert \vec u \rvert \ne \lvert \vec w \rvert$)

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that $\lvert \vec u \rvert = \lvert \vec w \rvert$, we could proceed as follows:

Note that
$(\vec u + \vec w) \cdot (\vec u - \vec w)
 = \lvert \vec u \rvert^2 - \lvert \vec w \rvert^2 = 0$,
so $\vec u + \vec w$ is perpendicular to $\vec u - \vec w$.

Then we can write $\vec w$ in a new coordinate system, perpendicular to the reflection:
$\vec w = \frac 12(\vec u + \vec w) - \frac 12 (\vec u - \vec w)$,
and we see that $s(\vec w) = -\frac 12(\vec u + \vec w) - \frac 12 (\vec u - \vec w) = -\vec u$, as required.

Furthermore, if $\lvert \vec u \rvert \ne \lvert \vec w \rvert$, then
we have $\lvert s(\vec w) \rvert = \lvert \vec w \rvert \ne \lvert -\vec u \rvert$, so $s(\vec w) \ne -\vec u$, and I therefore consider this answer to be pretty satisfactory.